# can we retrieve all fields in mongodb if we use group by clause without specifying each fields?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, database

there is a problem in mongo query i want like this:

suppose table is:

**Table name**: Employee

**Fields**: id, name, salary,age

```
select * from employee where name="xyz" group by salary;
```

if i use this query in mongodb so i have to write like this:

```
db.employee.aggregate([{$match:{"name":"xyz"}},{$group:{"_id":"$salary"}}]);
```

but i am not getting all the fields only getting salary we can do this if we specify fields name using $first but i dont wanna specify the fields name i need something like select * functionality in mongodb aggregation query.

Comment: That GROUP BY in invalid.

Comment: please refer to mongodb [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

Comment: i already did @UlugToprak but didnt find the solution i need to get all fields without specifying fields name

Comment: @jarlh  that was an example my main question is can we can all fields using group by in mongodb without specifying each fields?  Thanks

Comment: Use [$$ROOT](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-documents-by-author)

Comment: @Veeram  thanks but $$ROOT gets me the entire document without grouping the result :(

Comment: I think the link has grouping example. Can you show me your query ? Root will not do grouping. It is used with grouping to keep the entire document.

Comment: @Veeram  thanks i did it by using "$first": "$$ROOT"   its working now :)